# Angular 6, subscribing to Observables not working

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6 application where I cannot seem to properly subscribe to an observable in order to work out whether my user is logged in.

In my auth.guard I have the following, you can see where I've added a comment where my function never gets to:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn().pipe(map(loggedIn => {
    // I never get here
    if (!loggedIn) {
      window.location.href = environment.wolfUrl + 'account/login';;

    }
    return loggedIn;
  }));
}
```

Here's my isLoggedIn() function:

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
   this.userService.getUserWithRolesByUserName('test')
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.currentUser = result;
                if (this.currentUser.fullName != 'test name') {
                    subject.next(false);
                } else {
                    subject.next(true);
                }

            },
            () => { 
                subject.next(false);
            });
    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Here is my function getUserWithRolesByUserName

```
public getUserWithRolesByUserName(userName): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + '/getUserWithRolesByUserName?userName=' + userName);
}
```

Comment: is `userService.getUserWithRolesByUserName('test')` synchronious?

Comment: Good question, updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return an observable to the authguard, instead of subscribing, also then you can get rid of `subject`, which I see as redundant if you don't need it anywhere else. So modify `isLoggedIn()` to:

```ts
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.userService.getUserWithRolesByUserName('test')
    .pipe(
      first(),
      map((result) => {
        this.currentUser = result;
        if (this.currentUser.fullName != 'test name') {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false)),
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think getUserWithRolesByUserName is synchronious, and, as a result you emit event to subject before the subscription.
try

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.userService.getUserWithRolesByUserName('test')
        .pipe(
          first(),
          map(result => {
           this.currentUser = result;
           return this.currentUser.fullName == 'test name';
          }),
          catchError(() => of(false)),
          tap(value => this.subject.next(value)),
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that - where should I be unsubscribing (if anywhere)

Comment: router should both subscribe and unsubscribe to the observable you provided. anyway, with asyncronous getUserWithRolesByUserName my answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

In the 'canActivate' method, you need to subscribe to the observable returned by the 'isLoggedIn'  method. E.g.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn().pipe(map(loggedIn => {
    // I never get here
    if (!loggedIn) {
      window.location.href = environment.wolfUrl + 'account/login';;

    }
    return loggedIn;
  }))
  .subscribe(); // !!!
}
```

Comment: The pipe and map are basically as subscribe.